# Insert multiline sql statement phonegap

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova

I have one SQLite database which i exported in the form of sql statements.
Now I want to run all the sql statement in phonegap application to insert into database generated on rumtime.

Some statements have multiline data but I do not want want to convert these sql statement manually in javascript format. So what can I do to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can detect the end of SQL statements by searching for a semicolon at the end of a line, if you don't have any strings or comments where this character combination appears.